# Analysis: Would constructing lottery combinations by drawing one number at a time give combinations different probabilities of being drawn?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, gambling, lotteries

I’m not sure that all lottery combinations have the same probability of being drawn. Numbers are drawn one at a time to construct the $6$ numbered combination we see in a straight pick $6$ lottery (without extra power-ball structure). I’ll go through two cases I’ve examined to demonstrate my claim. I’ll work with the $6$ of $49$ Washington State Lottery which has $13,983,816$ combinations.

**Do you agree?**

**Case1:** This case will show the only **true way** to guarantee all combinations have the same probability of being drawn.
This case requires that all combinations of $6$ possible numbers to be generated pre-drawing, and that each combination is assigned a random index number $1$ through $13,983,816$ before each draw. If index numbers were assigned directly to each combination in an ascending order 1-to-1 assignment, there would be bias that would come from a Geometric (1/13,983,816) distribution of the index numbers. This case requires the generation of only $1$ random index number which will be the address into the lookup table containing the pre-generated combinations. **This guarantees equal probability to all combinations**.

$P = \frac{1}{13,983,816}$

**Case2:** (Posters Opinion, not approved by Mathematicians)

This case will show there is bias when combinations are constructed one number at a time, rather than just using the method in **Case1**. Those combinations come prepackaged.

To show this, we need only to analyze the probability of the first number drawn from the pool of $49$ numbers. It will be the first draw only that shows not all combinations have the same probability of being drawn… because they're constructed one number at a time due to a condition I call the **lockout by first draw**.

Let’s examine three combinations, a combination where every number in the combination is divisible by $8$, a combination where every number in the combination is prime, and a combination where every number in the combination is divisible by $5$.

There are $6$ numbers that are evenly divisible by 8, which yields only $1$ combination out of $13,983,816$.

There are $15$ numbers that are prime which yield $5005$ combinations out of $13,983,816$.

There are $9$ numbers that are divisible by $5$, which yield $84$ combinations out of $13,983,816$.

**The Process of Building Combinations**

To build any combination we need to select our first number out of the pool of $49$. Using basic probability here, the probability of selecting a number that is divisible by $8$ is $P_8 = \frac{6}{49}$ and the probability of selecting a number that is not divisible by $8$ is $P_{!8} = \frac{43}{49}$.

The probability to select a prime number is $P_P = \frac{15}{49}$ and the probability to select a number that is not prime is $P_{!P} = \frac{34}{49}$.

The probability to select a number divisible by $5$ is $P_5 = \frac{9}{49}$ and the probability to select a number that is not divisible by $5$ is $P_{!5} = \frac{40}{49}$.

So right away there’s a greater probability to **lockout by first draw** numbers that are divisible by $8$ because $\frac{43}{49} > \frac{6}{49}$.

This says clearly that the combination $8$ $16$ $24$ $32$ $40$ $48$ has a lower probability to be constructed through the process of building combinations one number at a time. Looking at the first draw probability shows this.

$P_P > P_5 > P_8$

$\frac{15}{49} > \frac{9}{49} > \frac{6}{49}$

$P_{!8} > P_{!5} > P_{!P}$

$\frac{43}{49} > \frac{40}{49} > \frac{34}{49}$

But no matter how you do the math, all combinations do have the same probability to be drawn... even if the combination is constructed one number at a time. Below for the only combination where all numbers are divisible by $8$.

$P = (\frac{6}{49})(\frac{5}{48})(\frac{4}{47})(\frac{3}{46})(\frac{2}{45})(\frac{1}{44}) = 13,983,816$

**Conclusion**

**Case2** tried to show that as combinations are constructed one number at a time, there may be bias in the draw. **But this is false**.

I took a beatdown on this post and had to revise it. I took a different approach on this topic and stepped on my own toes because I did not see the forest for the trees. I had to remove the section discussing "schemas" as this should've never been added here.

Comment: Not following. Why would you expect to see one of the very few draws with only multiples of $5$?

Comment: Your post is easy to read, it just doesn't make any sense.  Why do you think it's unusual or significant that a very rare event was not observed in a fairly small sample?

Comment: So you claim that an outcome such as 8 16 24 32 40 48 is less likely than 7 16 24 32 40 48, say? And if we follow gazillions of drawings, we will see that effect empirically and with significance? -- Now suppose some prankster manages to put ultrathin stickers (so that there is no phyisical effect on the balls) on the balls to the effect that 8 is now labelled "7" and 7 is labelled "8". Which combo will come out more often with the faked balls? 8 16 24 32 40 48 or 7 16 24 32 40 48? And what if each time the stickers are noticed and removed after the drawing but before announcing the result?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen lottery numbers are not drawn using balls in the Washington State Lottery. They are drawn using a computer at the their lottery office.

Comment: Just conceptually:  suppose, instead of numbers, you had $49$ species of insects.  Do you believe that some choice of $6$ insects is more probable than another if you choose them one at a time?  Which ones?

Comment: For that combination all divisible by $8$, what do you expect the sequential "lockout probability" at each draw should be (that leaves a "survival" probability of $1/13\,983\,816$ after 6 draws)?

Comment: Is this "lockout probability" different for other 6-numbered combinations, that would make the lottery unfair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not evidence of bias. If the $28$ different "schemas" were equally likely, *that* would be a biased drawing.

Why?

- Only $\binom93 = 84$ combinations out of $\binom{49}{6} = 13\,983\,816$ fall under schema $28$.
- Meanwhile, schema $7$ (all six numbers are from category B) corresponds to $\binom{20}{3} = 1\,140$ combinations out of $13\,983\,816$, so of course it should be more common.
- In your sample, the most common schema is schema $11$, with a $132$ pattern; it corresponds to $\binom 91 \binom{20}{3} \binom{20}{2} = 1\,949\,400$ different combinations. So of course it should be much more common than a schema with only $1\,140$ combinations!

However, it is silly to say that schema $11$ is somehow advantageous in the lottery. Sure, it is more likely that *some* combination of this type is chosen. But if you picked a schema-$11$ combination, and a schema-$11$ combination did come up, you still have only a $\frac{1}{1\,949\,400}$ chance of winning! On the other hand, if you picked a schema-$28$ combination, and a schema-$28$ combination comes up, you have a $\frac1{84}$ chance of winning. The overall probability is $\frac1{13\,983\,816}$ both ways, it's just that you've broken it up into stages differently.

Comment: Nice answer. The first and last paragraphs tell the essence of the story. The OP might be more likely to be convinced it you analyzed a much simpler lottery with fewer "schemas". But that would probably take more time than the question is worth and still not satisfy the OP.

Comment: Hi Misha. Would you agree that during the first number drawn, there is a higher probability to draw a prime numbered ball over a numbered ball divisible by $8$? There are $15$ prime numbers between $1$ and $49$ and only $6$ numbers that are divisible by $8$ ... so basic probability says yes we have a higher probability to draw a prime number ball... thus locking out that combination where all of its members are divisible by $8$. So it appears I'm correct. That's the bias... simple basic probability.

Comment: You're more likely to lock out the *single* combination where all six numbers are divisible by $8$ on the first turn, than you are to lock out the *set of 5005 combinations* where all six numbers are prime. There is no bias here. You should not expect the single combination where all numbers are divisible by 8 to be just as likely as the entire set of 5005 combinations where all numbers are prime. You should expect it to be 5005 times less likely. (Note: if you pick a *specific* set of 6 prime numbers, you're just as likely to "lock it out on the first turn" as the divisible-by-8 combination.)

Comment: If someone offered you a 1,000,000 dollars to reach in the pool of 49 numbers if you pull out any number divisible by $8$ or give you 100,000 dollars if you pull out any odd number. Which one offer will you take?

Comment: Obviously the first one; it's 10x the reward for something that's only approximately 1/4 as likely to happen. I don't think that's relevant to anything that's going on here, though. No matter how you carve out your schemas, you're not going to be able to go to the lottery organizers and say "the winning combination was all prime numbers, and so was mine, so I should get to win".

Comment: Here's a challenge for you; if you claim that when drawing balls one at a time, $\{8,16,24,32,40,48\}$ becomes less likely than its fair chance of $1$ in $13\,983\,816$, then *how much less likely*? What do you claim its probability of being drawn is?

Comment: That's not the point I was making. I used primes, and numbers divisible by 5 and 8 to illustrate a point of locking-out. I know it's possible to draw a combination with all its members divisible by 5... but since there are 40 numbers not divisible by 5 to choose from, the probability of drawing that type of combination is less likely "because" we are constructing a combination one number at a time.  I know mathematicians hate this question, but I think I'm correct.

Comment: Mathematicians don't hate "this question"; mathematicians hate it when someone claims "I'm correct" while dodging all attempts to engage with logic. Unless you answer my question, I don't think this conversation is likely to be productive, and I will bow out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151278/discussion-between-stevek-and-misha-lavrov).

Comment: @EthanBolker I agree with Mishas answer. I'll have to update my post.